# Rails 4 - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError with has_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

I have a problem with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`..

Here's my `Zone` model

```
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zones_users, inverse_of: :zone, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :users, through: :zones_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :zones_users, :update_only => true, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and `ZonesUser` model for the many-to-many association with the `User` model

```
class ZonesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :user
end
```

now in the `ZonesController` I'm permitting attributes and nested attributes for the `ZonesUser` association as follows

```
def zone_params
  params.require(:zone)
.permit(:id, :name, :description, :image, zones_users_attributes: [:user_id, :zone_id, :is_admin])
end
```

so that I can update the `Zone`'s data and the association all at once as follows

```
def update
  @zone = Zone.find_by_id(zone_params[:id])
  @zone.update(zone_params)
end
```

but this gives me the error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

and the error goes like this:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.2.4) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:564:in `init_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `build_association'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:250:in `build_record'
```

I'm using rails 4, and have read that `attr_accessible` is no longer used to allow access to nested models/associations, and that I should permit the attributes on a controller level (the permit zones_users_attributes part).. what have I missed?

Comment: Can you update your question with exact error message and the log that is generated in the server?

Comment: @Pavan I just updated the question with the first few lines of the log.